# java enum with enum in constructor

Tags: java, enums, enumset

**Is it possible to let a enum in java take a set of enums as as argument? If yes, then how do I implement it?**

When using this I whant to be able to say something like: Take a MODAL_SETTINGS.EDIT_MODAL_WINDOW and create this with the buttons MODAL_BUTTONS.SAVE & MODAL_BUTTONS.CANCEL.

This is what I have as of now

```
public enum MODAL_SETTINGS {
    NEW_MODAL_WINDOW(MODAL_BUTTONS.class),
    EDIT_MODAL_WINDOW(MODAL_BUTTONS.class),
    DELETE_MODAL_WINDOW(MODAL_BUTTONS.class);

    private EnumSet buttons;

    private MODAL_SETTINGS(EnumSet<MODAL_BUTTONS> buttons){

    }

}
public enum MODAL_BUTTONS {
    SAVE, UPDATE, CANCEL, DELETE
}
```

Comment: This isn't really relevant, but the normal naming convention for classes (including enum types) is to use CamelCase (even though the enum constants themselves use UPPER_CASE).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
NEW_MODAL_WINDOW(MODAL_BUTTONS.class),
```

I suspect you want this:

```
NEW_MODAL_WINDOW(EnumSet.allOf(MODAL_BUTTONS.class))
```

or

```
NEW_MODAL_WINDOW(EnumSet.of(MODAL_BUTTONS.SAVE, MODAL_BUTTONS.CANCEL))
```

(etc).

Otherwise you're just passing a `Class<T>`, not an `EnumSet`.

Answer (score 10):

No problem:

```
enum Color {YELLOW, BLUE, GREEN}

enum Environment { 
     SUN(Color.YELLOW), OCEAN(Color.BLUE), TREE(Color.GREEN);

     private Color color;
     private Environment(Color color) {
       this.color = color;
     }
     public Color getColor() {
       return color;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look at this:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;
public class EnumTest {
public static enum MODAL_BUTTONS {
    SAVE, UPDATE, CANCEL, DELETE
}
public static enum MODAL_SETTINGS {
    NEW_MODAL_WINDOW(EnumSet.of(MODAL_BUTTONS.SAVE, MODAL_BUTTONS.UPDATE)),
    EDIT_MODAL_WINDOW(EnumSet.of(MODAL_BUTTONS.UPDATE, MODAL_BUTTONS.CANCEL)),
    DELETE_MODAL_WINDOW(EnumSet.of(MODAL_BUTTONS.CANCEL, MODAL_BUTTONS.DELETE));

    private EnumSet<MODAL_BUTTONS> buttons;

    MODAL_SETTINGS(EnumSet<MODAL_BUTTONS> buttons){
        this.buttons = buttons;
    }
    EnumSet<MODAL_BUTTONS> getBtns() {
        return this.buttons;
    }
}
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(MODAL_SETTINGS.NEW_MODAL_WINDOW.getBtns());
        System.out.println(MODAL_SETTINGS.EDIT_MODAL_WINDOW.getBtns());
        System.out.println(MODAL_SETTINGS.DELETE_MODAL_WINDOW.getBtns());
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
[SAVE, UPDATE]
[UPDATE, CANCEL]
[CANCEL, DELETE]
```